# REACT Serve file in base64 string for download

Tags: reactjs, file, base64

I have the name and the content of a file (pdf) as an base64 string available in my REACT app. Now, I want to add a button for downloading the file. So, the user can press the button and the download dialog of the browser should pop up.

Any ideas how I can realize this? I am using REACT-bootstrap so my button looks like this:

```
return(
  <Button onClick={() => filedownload()}>
      Download
  </Button>
);
```

```js
function filedownload() {
  const filename = 'filename.txt';
  const b63string = 'hereisthelongbase64string...';

  // ???

}
```

Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with keeping it simple

```jsx
const filename = 'filename.txt';
const b64string = 'hereisthelongbase64string...';

return (
  <a
    className="styled-like-a-button"
    download={filename}
    href={`data:application/pdf;base64,${b64string}`}
  >Download</a>
);
```

Comment: Wow! So simple! Thanks a lot! Is working fine for me!